# su - username command doesn't act as expected

Tags: linux, command-line, redhat, su

I am trying to switch to another user using `su` command, but it doesn't work as expected.

**What I am expecting:**

```
[root@ubuntu ~]# su testuser
[testuser@ubuntu root]#
```

**What actually happens:**

```
[root@ubuntu ~]# su testuser
bash-4.2$
```

`whoami` command:

```
bash-4.2$ whoami
testuser
```

Comment: Why do you expect that? By convention, the prompt should not use `#` for a non-`root` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The testuser might not have the same bash configuration. So the prompt might look different. Check the current user with `whoami` after you switched the user.

Comment: So the prompt just look different because they are configured differently for the two users. See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/customize-bash-prompt on how to configure the prompt.